# Cisco Nexus vPC LACP bonding with server issue

Tags: cisco, switch, linux, cisco-nexus, vpc

I am configuring `vPC` end to end till my server to get more bandwidth, and following is my scenario

[image]

I am seeing one strange thing which is i configured vPC on N3k switch and then i configured my Linux server for link aggregation `802.3ad` bonding and then i restart server so far all good, i can see correct bonding configuration in `/proc/net/bonding/bind0` and my server also started ping but i found i got packet loss in ping, later i found on switch its showing `vpc` is down but wondering how i am getting ping?

```
N3k# show vpc 1


vPC status
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id   Port   Status Consistency Reason                     Active vlans
--   ----   ------ ----------- ------                     ------------
134  Po1  down*  success     success                    -
```

Later i did `shut` & `no shut` on `Port-Channel 1` and that immediately bring up vpc

```
N3k# show vpc 1


vPC status
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id   Port   Status Consistency Reason                     Active vlans
--   ----   ------ ----------- ------                     ------------
131  Po1  up     success     success                    10,20,30
```

My VPC domain config

```
vpc domain 204
  peer-switch
  role priority 10
  peer-keepalive destination 10.29.0.51 source 10.29.0.50
  auto-recovery
  ip arp synchronize
```

This is my vPC config

```
interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
  speed 10000
  channel-group 1 mode active

interface port-channel1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
  speed 10000
  vpc 1
```

This is my Linux server config

ifcfg-bond0

```
NAME=bond0
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=500 downdelay=1000 lacp_rate=1"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

ifcfg-bond0.10

```
NAME=bond0.10
DEVICE=bond0.10
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
VLAN=yes
ONPARENT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

## Question:

1. How does server pinging even if `vpc` is down on switch?
2. Why do i need to `shut/no shut` vpc to bring it up vpc? is this normal?
3. I installed 30 servers on same vpc cluster and all had same issue, every time i have to go to switch and need to do port-channel `shut/no shut`
4. Am i missing something here?

## Update - 1

For testing i reboot server and found server is up but switch vpc is down and on switch i am seeing following logs, This is strange issue.

```
sw1# show logging | grep "Ethernet1/37"
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:13 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_INITIALIZING: Interface Ethernet1/37 is down (Initializing)
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:13 sw1 %ETH_PORT_CHANNEL-5-PORT_INDIVIDUAL_DOWN: individual port Ethernet1/37 is down
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:15 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_INITIALIZING: Interface Ethernet1/37 is down (Initializing)
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:18 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-SPEED: Interface Ethernet1/37, operational speed changed to 10 Gbps
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:18 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_DUPLEX: Interface Ethernet1/37, operational duplex mode changed to Full
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:18 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_RX_FLOW_CONTROL: Interface Ethernet1/37, operational Receive Flow Control state changed to off
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:18 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_TX_FLOW_CONTROL: Interface Ethernet1/37, operational Transmit Flow Control state changed to off
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:28 sw1 %ETH_PORT_CHANNEL-4-PORT_INDIVIDUAL: port Ethernet1/37 is operationally individual
    2018 Jul  9 14:28:28 sw1 %ETHPORT-5-IF_UP: Interface Ethernet1/37 is up in mode trunk
```

Server side i am seeing following error

```
[root@Linux ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages
Jul  9 10:45:47 s_sys@linux kernel: : [  321.299960] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
Jul  9 10:46:11 s_sys@linux kernel: : [  345.300288] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
```

Linux server side i am seeing following

```
[root@Linux ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 500
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 1000

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 6c:3b:e5:b0:7a:40
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 2
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 13
    Partner Key: 32883
    Partner Mac Address: 00:23:04:ee:be:cc
```

Comment: What does the log show when the vPC is first brought up/the server is booted? My guess is there's a BPDU from the server and the `bpduguard` option shuts the bond.

Comment: In logs i am not seeing anything interesting, all standard logs IF up IF down, should i need to increase logging, if you then do you know what logging level i need to set?, i will try to remove `bpduguard` and try will update you result soon

Comment: Make sure you've got *active* LACP configured on at least one side - a passive-passive LACP trunk won't come up (but should as a single interface).

Comment: @Zac67 I have updated output of linux side boding its saying `Dynamic link aggregation` so does that means auto right?   as soon as i set `channel-group 1 mode on` it brought up `vpc` but server not pinging

Comment: I found issue, on switch side i have configured `switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30`  but on server side i only configured `VLAN 10,20` it was the issue, look like LACP negotiating VLAN also, How to stop VLAN negotiation on LACP, reason we set multiple VLAN on trunk so it will allow us to setup server dynamically and we don't need to go to every switch and adjust VLAN, Anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: frustrated now, look like its not VLAN issue, i did same thing on other server and it didn't work :( still digging

Comment: You may also want to check if  `lacp suspend-individual` is active on port-channel interfaces by default on that  switch. I found it to be active by default on N3K-3164Q-40GE with 7.0(3)I4(6). This gave the server guys a hard time bootstrapping their server, because the bonding driver isn't running during all phases of the setup (or boot) phase, and the port remained suspended. I had to turn it off  for all port-channel objects (`no lacp suspend-individual`) to allow the ports to come up. Note that this might be a bad idea for inter switch links, but for edge ports to servers it is acceptable.

Comment: Please share the VPC configuration of 3K and 9K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

OMG! Problem was **downdelay=1000** option from Linux BONDING_OPTS, As soon as i removed that everything started working, I reboot server 10 time and every single time vpc was up.

I don't know why nexus doesn't like **downdelay=1000**

Now my config look like following after fix:

```
NAME=bond0
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=500 lacp_rate=1"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

- Can someone explain in comments why downdelay doesn't work?

Comment: From https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt: "Use integer value for delaying disabling a link by this number (in ms) after
the link failure has been detected. Must be a multiple of miimon. Default
value is zero. See HA section for additional info." Makes little sense with your problem all right...

Comment: Please accept your own question, so that it does not keep popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove first the lacp_rate option and check that the LACP rate of the bonding interface changes from `fast` to `slow`

Explanation: LACP Rate on the switch is slow (30sec) by default and you set it to fast (1sec) on the server-side. That means your server sends and expects LACPPDU's every second where the switch only sends them every 30 seconds.
A mismatch tends to cause issues (mostly on the server-side), they should be the same on both ends. You could also set it to fast on the switch interface `lacp rate fast` but the recommendation is using the default (slow) and should be good for most cases - unless you have special requirements.